# HTML width with an xsl:value

Tags: javascript, java, xslt

I found this code to create a pie chart with java. I would like to put xsl:value instead of the numbers as well as `xsl:value` for each category, is that possible ?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Kindly delete that post, I just found out I just have to write the normal xsl code and it works :)

Comment: Users can delete their own questions if the question has zero answers or
only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes. Simply click the delete link underneath the question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions